# Model class doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, apscheduler

I use Django (1.8.1). 
I need some python code to run at Django startup (apscheduler initialization), so in one of my project application, named for example `my_app` I created `apps.py` and declared appconfig `ready` method according to Django docs.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from django.apps import AppConfig
from my_app.views import some_shecheduled_method

class ManagerConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_app'
    verbose_name = "My Application"
    scheduler = None

    def ready(self):
        ManagerConfig.scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
        ManagerConfig.scheduler.add_job(some_shecheduled_method, 'interval', seconds=15)
        ManagerConfig.scheduler.start()
```

Also in application `__init__.py`:

```
default_app_config = 'my_app.apps.ManagerConfig'
```

But after adding this to `__init__.py` in application log I see next message for all models in project:

```
05/04 16:00:25|py.warnings:116:WARNING ./authsystem/models.py:51: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class authsystem.models.UserActionLog doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
  class UserActionLog(Model):
```

Also when I use this `apscheduler` in Django it hangs sometimes when I reload application (I use `uwsgi`+`py-autoreload=5`), may be there are some mistakes in my approach and I need to use another way to initialize scheduler

Comment: Did you declare an `app_label` in the `class Meta` of your `UserActionLog` model? Try doing this: `class Meta: app_label = 'my_app'`

Comment: No, this warning appears for all project models (for models of all applications not only my_app), so do I need mandatory to declare Meta my_app on each model and specify application name where it belongs?

Comment: There are some work arounds, but it is easier and preferred to designate the app label for each model you have

Comment: Did you solve this? I've been googling for two fu..ing days and I can't solve it.